# gap under div in firefox

Tags: html, css

I have this html with a wordpress theme

```
div class="fullWidthDarkBlue">
<div class="hpRentArrears">
<section id="black-studio-tinymce-8" class="widgetcontainer widget_black_studio_tinymce"><div class="textwidget"><h2>Rent Arrears</h2>
<p>Does ...t on your behalf.</p>
</div>
</section>
</div>
<div class="clearer"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">...
```

And some css like this:

```
#footer {
margin-top:0px;
border:none;
}

.fullWidthDarkBlue {
width:100%;
background:#365162;
padding-top:30px;
}

.hpRentArrears {
width:346px;
float:left;
background:#f2f1ed;
border:2px solid #a7cfdb;
}

.hpRentArrears p {
margin:0;
}

.clearer {
clear:both; 
}
```

All works well except in FF there is a gap between the bottom of the dark blue box and the footer. I find I can remove this gap by putting a border onto the #footer - but I don't really want to

[image: shows offending gap]

What's causing the gap and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Use Firebug and check your "Box" dimensions, considering padding, margin, height, etc.

Comment: yes, I have done all that. Tuned them, added different ones and so on

Comment: Argghh, dreamweaver!! AARRGGGGHHHH

Comment: dreamweaver - yes, but not really relevant is it

Comment: post your whole code here or jsfiddle or provide URL

Answer (score 0):

I tested your piece of code, its working fine in ff, safari and chrome. Must be the footer inside element that is throwing some margin.

Share your code and i will fix it.